# Rendering Plot and Table Within One Function

Tags: python, py-shiny

Currently i am working on my first webapplication in Shiny. Through text input from the user a MySQL query is being made and data is being retrieved from the SQL database. In my code snippet I removed the queries to keep it more clear. The data is then being used to create a pandas dataframe `df_meetdata` and a graph `fig`. Currently the app shows the graph but not the dataframe since it is not possible to return multiple variables in Shiny. Does someone know a way how I can show both the graph and dataframe?

```
app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.layout_sidebar(
        ui.panel_sidebar(
            ui.input_slider("n", "N", 0, 100, 20),
            ui.input_text("txt", "Referentienummer", value=""),
            ui.input_action_button("run", "Run"),
            ui.input_action_button("clear", "Clear"),
            ui.input_action_button("export", "Export")
        ),
        ui.panel_main(
            ui.output_text("nmr"),
            ui.output_text("print_referentienummer"),
            ui.output_plot("get_absorptie_spectrum"),
            ui.output_table("table_model"),
        ),
    ),
)


def server(input, output, session):
    @output
    @render.text
    def nmr():
        return f"input = {input.n()}"

    @output
    @render.text
    def print_referentienummer():
        return f"Referentienummer = {input.txt()}"

    @output
    @render.plot
    @reactive.event(input.run, ignore_none=True)
    def get_absorptie_spectrum():
        # Ophalen datum meting + sensorID om absorptiewaarden uit de mysql db te kunnen halen
        referentienummer = input.txt()
        
        #SQL queries for retrieving the data#

        df_meetdata = pd.DataFrame(
           {"BlueBox": bluebox_naam, "Referentienummer": referentienummer, "Datum": date_time,
            "ABS >= 2": max_absorptie}, index=[0])

        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.plot(golflengte, absorptie_waarden)
        ax.set_title(referentienummer)

        return fig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the people that want to know the answer i found it myself :). I looked through the documentation and i found the function that was needed, it was the reactive.value() function. Ive created a function that retrieves all the data from the MySQL database. The data that I needed to render are being stored in variables and used in seperate render functions.

```
    app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.layout_sidebar(
        ui.panel_sidebar(
            ui.input_slider("n", "N", 0, 100, 20),
            ui.input_text("txt", "Referentienummer", value=""),
            ui.input_action_button("run", "Run"),
            ui.input_action_button("clear", "Clear"),
            ui.input_action_button("export", "Export")
        ),
        ui.panel_main(
            ui.output_plot("render_absorptie_spectrum"),
            ui.output_table("render_bluebox_data"),
        ),
    ),
)


def server(input, output):
    val_df_meetdata = reactive.Value()
    val_absorptie_waarden = reactive.Value()
    val_referentienummer = reactive.Value()

    @reactive.Effect
    @reactive.event(input.run)
    def get_sql_data():
        referentienummer = input.txt()

        # SQL queries. The results are being stored in the variables df_meetdata and absorptie_waarden which are used in the following lines #

        val_df_meetdata.set(df_meetdata)
        val_absorptie_waarden.set(absorptie_waarden)
        val_referentienummer.set(referentienummer)

    @output
    @render.plot
    def render_absorptie_spectrum():
        absorptie_waarden = val_absorptie_waarden.get()
        referentienummer = val_referentienummer.get()

        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.plot(golflengte, absorptie_waarden)
        ax.set_title(referentienummer)

        return fig

    @output
    @render.table
    def render_bluebox_data():
        df_meetdata = val_df_meetdata.get()

        return df_meetdata

app = App(app_ui, server)
```